# Using scantxouset method on bitcoind JSON RPC

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, scantxoutset

BitcoinRPC class from here (ruby): https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

btc = BitcoinRPC.new("http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:18332")

btc.getaddress    => "2NCixvAERq3eDt31jM7eYATGiHdTEcizQkj"     THIS WORKS

arguments =  { action: 'start', scanobjects: ["addr(mfskMRWntcPYdDgTJRJdwzdKiiHJikfvH4)"] }.to_json

btc.scantxoutset(arguments)  => BitcoinRPC::JSONRPCError: {"code"=>-8, "message"=>"Invalid command"}   Doesn't work...

Comment: what version of Bitcoin Core are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 0.18.0

$ bitcoin-cli --version
Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.18.0.0-g2472733a24a9364e4c6233ccd04166a26a68cc65

Comment: I'm not a ruby guy, but perhaps the arguments are the wrong format. Have you tried 2 different arguments? The first is just a string "start" and the second is the json-stringified array?

Comment: This is old but did you try changing ["addr(mfskMRWntcPYdDgTJRJdwzdKiiHJikfvH4)"]. to. ["addr('mfskMRWntcPYdDgTJRJdwzdKiiHJikfvH4')"]